# Phonegap IOS Ajax request- Memory consumption is 1GB+

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova, memory-management

Since i am a beginner in phonegap on IOS, facing some memory management issue. I have created a phonegap project with a couple of Ajax requests.

After installing app, it performs Synchronization of data (around 20 tables) from server database(MySql) to localdatabase(WebSql). The data is sent and received using Ajax request and REST api.

Everything works fine on Android device BUT, when i build and run the app on IOS device(iPad) or Simulator(iPhone 6s plus). Initially the memory consumption is 93MB After login the page is redirected to synchronization and the memory gradually rises from 93MB to 1.42GB and so on causing the application to abnomally abort throwing memory warning. The data retrived from services is in JSon format.

The JSon data might contains 2500 records, so i modified the service to produce only 500/100/10 records and consume using pagination technique but still the memory shoots above 1 GB.

What approach shall i use for the synchronization on IOS since the data to be synchronized is huge.

code :-

```
db.transaction(function(tx)
   {
     tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS apm_t(apm_id int(11) NOT NULL, srNo_vc varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,and so on..)");

   //Retrive server data
   $http.get("http://192.168.1.99:8080/myplanner-rest-api/apms")
       .success(function(response) {
          for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
             //Insert server data into local database
             myService.setApm_t(response[i].apm_id, response[i].srNo_vc, and so on…);
             }
          });
});


myApp.service('myService', function($q) {
  this.setApm_t = function(apm_id, srNo_vc,and so on..)
                  {
                   db.transaction(function(tx)
                                 {
                                  return tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO apm_t (apm_id, srNo_vc, and so on..) VALUES(?, ?, and so on..)", [apm_id, srNo_vc,and so on..], function(tx, res)
                                             {
                                              return true;
                                             });
                                 });
                                 return false;
                    }
 });
```

Please need some expert suggestions and guidence. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using an empty phonegap app to see the "basic" memory usage? Are you using plugins? What version of cordova are you using?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes i did check the memory usage of hello world project without any ajax requests which was around 40-43MB. org.apache.cordova.device is the only plugin used. Using Cordova version 3.3.0.

Comment: It will be helpful if you post your js code. From what you're saying, seems that you have some memory leaks.

Comment: Please check the code snippet. I have been thinking of retriving the data in the form of JSon file from the server and then delete the file after pushing all the records from the file into local DB, But i am not sure if it will be helpful in reducing the memory usage.

Comment: Brodysoft SQLitePlugin instead of WebSql database worked for me and the memory has been under control untill now. 105 MB is the maximum consumption. @lifeisfoo thanks for that memory leak hint :)